# Get history of transactions to specific account (EthereumJ)

Tags: transactions, ethereumj

How to get all the transactions which were received by some specific account (not necessary owned by me)? I need something like the [list provided by the Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0xe985f4e25def8cec0d57e8eaac0b4fd6e0da8a73).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the most comfortable solution is if you use the Etherscan API. With this, your problem is solvable with only one api call;) More info [here](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts) at the ***Get a list of 'Normal' Transactions By Address*** paragraph.

Here is an example api call, which lists all the transactions received by the address: `0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae`;

```
http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

Here you just have to replace the address field for the one you are interested in and at the end of the call insert your api key token. Good luck!